# Identifying the field causing the error in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, asp.net, crystal-reports

When I try to export to disk a crystal report from within asp.net code, crystal report throw an exception. Exception just says "Invalid object format", which means clearly some field in report is failing data type conversion. Now, I can try and resolve the problem, if I know the field name.

Sadly, crystal report is stupid, and never adds the exact field name in exception message. So, I am unable to find which field is causing the problem. Unless I can find that field, there is no way for me to resolve the issue. So, all I want is a way to identify that field.

P.S. This issue happened when we moved all of our reports to latest version of Crystal Reports, and happens only with couple reports, out of the hundreds we have.

Edit:

Stack trace of the error I am receiving

```
CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.InternalException was unhandled by user code
  HResult=-2147221760
  Message=
Error in File RepairTag {40C68F49-F0B7-46D6-9E89-6E105808B13B}.rpt:
Invalid object format name.
  Source=CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.DataSetConversion
  StackTrace:
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ConvertDotNetToErom.ThrowDotNetException(Exception e)
       at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.FormatEngine.Export(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
       at CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine.ReportDocument.ExportToDisk(ExportFormatType formatType, String fileName)
       at FANUC.CSMS.Common.BusinessTier.ReportBC.GenerateReportAndExportToDisk(String strExportFormat, String strMapPath) in d:\FANUC\CSMS\BusinessTier\Common\ReportBC.cs:line 227
       at FANUC.CSMS.Common.BusinessTier.ReportBC.GenerateReportWithSelection(String strReportID, String strClause, String strExportFormat, Row objLocalizedNames, String strSortFields, Hashtable htblLocalizedNamesForSubReport, String strFilterString, Row objParamaterFieldsValues, String strMapPath, String strFontOverwriteReqd, String strGroup) in d:\FANUC\CSMS\BusinessTier\Common\ReportBC.cs:line 180
       at FANUC.CSMS.Reports.Web.Reports.Page_Load(Object sender, EventArgs e) in d:\FANUC\CSMS\CSMSWeb\Reports\Reports.aspx.cs:line 98
       at System.Web.UI.Control.LoadRecursive()
       at System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
  InnerException: System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
       HResult=-2147483077
       Message=
Error in File RepairTag {40C68F49-F0B7-46D6-9E89-6E105808B13B}.rpt:
Invalid object format name.
       Source=rptcontrollers.dll
       ErrorCode=-2147483077
       StackTrace:
            at CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.Controllers.ReportSourceClass.Export(ExportOptions pExportOptions, RequestContext pRequestContext)
            at CrystalDecisions.ReportSource.EromReportSourceBase.ExportToStream(ExportRequestContext reqContext)
       InnerException:
```

Comment: Is it still possible to run the same report on the old version. 
Does it run within CR when you hit Show Preview?

Comment: Yeah, I tried that. Works wonderfully on old version, but not in CR. Anyway, I kept looking further, and turns out it was DB access issue. Talk about stupid error tracing. Took me 3 hours to find the issue.